# how to call descendant function from a base class?

Tags: c++

I have a question for this scheme:

```
class computer_mouse
{
    left_click() { };
    track_wheel() { };
    right_click() { };
}

class game_mouse: public computer_mouse
{
    double_shot() { };
    throw_grenade() { };
    sit_down() { };
}

class design_mouse: public computer_mouse
{
    increase_zoom() { };
    decrease_zoom() { };
}


class computer
{
    computer_mouse *my_mouse;
}
```

I want to do this:

```
computer_mouse *my_mouse = new game_mouse();
my_mouse->double_shot();
```

How can I call a descendant function from a base class?

Comment: Understanding why you want to do this would allow people to respond with the best method of doing this.

Comment: your class methods don't have return types?  Are you really programming in C++?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use e.g. [`static_cast`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Static_cast) for that:

```
computer_mouse *my_mouse = new game_mouse();

static_cast<game_mouse*>(my_mouse)->double_shot();
```

From the above linked Wikipedia page:

> The static_cast operator can be used for operations such as
>
> - Converting a pointer of a base class to a pointer of a derived class,

Comment: @ JoachimPileBorg, is there any reason you would prefer static_cast to dynamic_cast?  In this situation the dynamic_cast is "safer" (although its a bit smelly), right?  You get the advantage of RTTI and it will return a NULL pointer if the cast cannot be performed.

Comment: @JoshPetitt Yes `dynamic_cast` uses RTTI, but remember that the R stands for _runtime_ which means added code by the compiler which is not always wanted. And since `dynamic_cast` can return `nullptr` you have to add extra code yourself as well for that check. Also, the compiler will try to make sure that the cast is okay when using `static_cast`, so in a case like this it's preferable to use `static_cast`.

Comment: @ JoachimPileborg I realize the R part.  I guess in this case I'd have to resort to "not enough information" :-)  I'd personally prefer "safety" over "performance", but either will do.

Answer (score 1):

By using `static_cast`:

```
static_cast<game_mouse*>(my_mouse)->double_shot();
```

However, the methods should be public, and not private!

```
class game_mouse: public computer_mouse
{
public:
    double_shot() { };
    throw_grenade() { };
    sit_down() { };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't do this:

```
computer_mouse *my_mouse = new game_mouse();
my_mouse->double_shot();
```

Do this:

```
game_mouse *my_mouse = new game_mouse();
my_mouse->double_shot();
```